# Automatic token creation on new user addition from forms

Tags: python, django, authentication, token

I need a way of creating a token automatically when a new user is created from forms. Using the signals @receiver I am only able to create token automatically from the admin site, but i need to create a token when a new user is added (from anywhere).

this is the code in my models.py to capture the post_save.

```html
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

How can I use this,when user form is POSTed. (I am able to save the user from template, but token are not generated automatically)

Comment: Attaching a receiver to your `User` model is the way to go, this should include the admin as well. Perhaps you can post more of your work so we can take a look.

Comment: You should edit your answer or delete this one if this is the same of [Automatic Token creation through User Creation Form in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27631656/automatic-token-creation-through-user-creation-form-in-django)

Comment: @abstractpaper , I found a work around. I changed the sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL to sender=User

And it seems to be working!